# SimpleXml::xpath() after simplexml_import_dom() operates on the whole DomDocument and not just the Node

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I'm not sure if this is the expected behavior or if I'm doing something wrong:

```
<?php

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foobar>
<foo>
<nested>
<img src="example1.png"/>
</nested>
</foo>
<foo>
<nested>
<img src="example2.png"/>
</nested>
</foo>
</foobar>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('foo')[0];

$simplexml = simplexml_import_dom($node);
echo $simplexml->asXML() . "\n";

echo " === With // ====\n";
var_dump($simplexml->xpath('//img'));


echo " === With .// ====\n";
var_dump($simplexml->xpath('.//img'));
```

Even though I only imported a specific DomNode, and asXml() returns only that part, the xpath() still seems to operate on the whole document.

I can prevent that by using .//img, but that seemed rather strange to me.

Result:

```
<foo>
<nested>
<img src="example1.png"/>
</nested>
</foo>
 === With // ====
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#4 (1) {
    public $@attributes =>
    array(1) {
      'src' =>
      string(12) "example1.png"
    }
  }
  [1] =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#5 (1) {
    public $@attributes =>
    array(1) {
      'src' =>
      string(12) "example2.png"
    }
  }
}
 === With .// ====
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  class SimpleXMLElement#5 (1) {
    public $@attributes =>
    array(1) {
      'src' =>
      string(12) "example1.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected behavior. You're importing an DOM element node into an SimpleXMLElement. This does not modify the XML document in the background - the node keeps its context.

Here are Xpath expressions that go up (`parent::`, `ancestor::`) or to siblings (`preceding-sibling::`, `following-sibling::`).

Location paths starting with a `/` are always relative to the document, not the context node. An explicit reference to the current node with the `.` avoids that trigger. `.//img` is short for `current()/descendant-or-self::img` - an alternative would be `descendant::img`.

However you don't need to convert the DOM node into a SimpleXMLElement to use Xpath.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//foo[1]') as $foo) {
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('string(.//img/@src)', $foo)
  );
}
```

Output:

```
string(12) "example1.png"
```

`//foo[1]` fetches the first `foo` element node in the document. If here is no matching element in the document it will return an empty list. Using `foreach` allows to avoid an error in that case. It will be iterated once or never.

`string(.//img/@src)` fetches the `src` attribute of descendant `img` elements and casts the first one into a string. If here is no matching node the return value will be and empty string. The second argument to `DOMXpath::evaluate()` is the context node.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Good to know, was not very intuitive at first but makes sense. I'm aware I can use xpath on DOM as well, this is just an example snippet extracted from a larger piece of code (where I am doing that too). I guess I could refactor it to only use DOM but it was easier to do the additional processing on the image elements and its surrounding structure with SimpleXML :)